# Elastic Beanstalk link/alias cmake3 to cmake

Tags: amazon-web-services, cmake, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sudo

I have installed cmake3 through yum on my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance:

```
packages: 
  yum:
    cmake3: []
```

However when running a pip install that requires cmake, I'm getting an error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cmake': 'cmake'`

How can I alias cmake3 for cmake? I have tried the following and it is resulting in the same error message.

```
container_commands:
  01_link_cmake:
    command: "ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake"
```

The reason I do not install `cmake: []` is because I need version 3.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it. I realized that the pip package install happened before the ln -s container command. So even if my alias was happening, it was happening too late in the process.

Instead, what I needed to do was

```
container_commands:
  01_link_cmake:
    command: ln -s /usr/bin/cmake3 /usr/bin/cmake
  02_upgrade_pip:
    command: "python -m pip install --upgrade pip"
    leader_only: true
  03_install_package:
    command: "python -m pip install <package that requires cmake>"
    leader_only: true
```